# Add CSS if text is larger than textbox

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make a textbox with a scrolling effect on hover, but only if the text is longer than the textbox. So here is my try: https://jsfiddle.net/SynapticError/wqh4ts3n/35/

- If the text is longer than the textbox, the text should 'scroll' on hover.
- If the text is shorter than the textbox, it should do nothing.

In pseudo code it would be like this:

```
IF scrollcontent.width > navbes.width
{ add css <style type="text/css">navbes:hover .scrollcontent {left: -100px; transition-duration:3s;}</style> }
```

I don't know how to make it right. I've tried many different ways, but none works. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: `<navbes>` is not a valid `html` element

Comment: Instead adding inline style add a class. and in your fiddle you don't load jquery https://jsfiddle.net/6z0d1ar0/1/

Comment: Is the the effect you're going for? https://jsfiddle.net/wqh4ts3n/36/

Comment: All of your indentation is / well, isn't. I suggest you check out standard indentation style

Comment: Well, - I think this whole idea is pretty terrible... but I started writing it out anyway. The animation speed needs to be based on the length - or it's just not readable. I would suggest rethinking this design, but here are my tests in case they help: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/d6871wcp/

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelCoker. :)

Comment: @LiaMiller you're welcome. Is that what you're trying to do? I can answer if you like, but I wasn't sure. You also don't need javascript or jquery for that. You can just do it in css.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your overflow "hidden" to "auto" :

```
navbes {background-color:#5A412E; display:block; width: 180px; height: 50px; 
overflow: auto; 
position: relative; padding:0px;}
```